# Problema con mi crud php ajax al insertar en mysql

Tags: php, ajax, json

No puedo envíar datos a mybd, cabe resaltar que no es problema de conexión, ya que al eliminar registros, todo funciona bien; el problema es al insertar datos en mi bd.

Llevo más de un mes botándole cabeza a este y no he podido.

Otra cosa es que cuando guardo se repite el último registro de la bd. console.log(data) me manda los datos del registro anterior, por lo que supongo que el error esta en la data del AJAX; ya probé introducirlos en un *array* o en una variable global pero no me ha funcionado.

```js
$("#btnNuevo1").click(function(){

            $("#formConductores").trigger("reset");
            $(".modal-header").css("background-color", "#28a745");
            $(".modal-header").css("color", "white");
            $(".modal-title").text("Registro Conductor");            
            $("#ModalConductores").modal("show");        
            id=null;
            opcion = 1; //alta
              });
            
            $("#formConductores").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();    
     
        nombre_y_apellidos= $.trim($('#nombre_y_apellidos').val());
        tipo_de_documento = $.trim($('#tipo_de_documento').val());
        numero_de_documento = $.trim($('#numero_de_documento').val());
        fecha_de_expedicion = $.trim($('#fecha_de_expedicion').val());
        telefono_o_celular = $.trim($('#telefono_o_celular').val());
        direccion = $.trim($('#direccion').val());
        correo = $.trim($('#correo').val());
        eps = $.trim($('#eps').val());
        arl = $.trim($('#arl').val());
        afp = $.trim($('#afp').val());
        departamento_name = $.trim($('#lista_reproduccion option:selected').text());
        ciudad_name = $.trim($('#videos').val());


          $.ajax({
            data: {nombre_y_apellidos:nombre_y_apellidos, tipo_de_documento:tipo_de_documento,  numero_de_documento:numero_de_documento, fecha_de_expedicion:fecha_de_expedicion, telefono_o_celular:telefono_o_celular, direccion:direccion, correo:correo, eps:eps, arl:arl, afp:afp, departamento_name:departamento_name, ciudad_name:ciudad_name, id:id, opcion:opcion},
             url:"bd/crudcond.php",
             type:"POST",
             dataType:"json",
             success:function(data){
                
                    id = data[0].id;      
                    nombre_y_apellidos = data[0].nombre_y_apellidos;
                    tipo_de_documento = data[0].tipo_de_documento;
                    numero_de_documento = data[0].numero_de_documento;
                    fecha_de_expedicion = data[0].fecha_de_expedicion;
                    telefono_o_celular = data[0].telefono_o_celular;
                    direccion = data[0].direccion;
                    correo = data[0].correo;
                    eps = data[0].eps;
                    arl = data[0].arl;
                    afp = data[0].afp;
                    departamento_name = data[0].departamento_name;
                    ciudad_name = data[0].ciudad_name;
                    console.log(data);
                  if(opcion == 1){tablaConductores.row.add(["", id, nombre_y_apellidos,tipo_de_documento,numero_de_documento,fecha_de_expedicion,telefono_o_celular,direccion,correo,eps,arl,afp,departamento_name,ciudad_name]).draw();}
                else{tablaConductores.row(fila).dat(["", id, nombre_y_apellidos,tipo_de_documento,numero_de_documento,fecha_de_expedicion,telefono_o_celular, direccion,correo,eps,arl,afp,departamento_name,ciudad_name]).draw();} 
             }
            
            });
           
            $("#ModalConductores").modal("hide");   

     
    });
```

```
<?php
include_once '../bd/conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

// Recepción de los datos enviados mediante POST desde el JS   

$nombre_y_apellidos = (isset($_POST['nombre_y_apellidos'])) ? $_POST['nombre_y_apellidos'] : '';
$tipo_de_documento = (isset($_POST['tipo_de_documento'])) ? $_POST['tipo_de_documento'] : '';
$numero_de_documento = (isset($_POST['numero_de_documento'])) ? $_POST['numero_de_documento'] : '';
$fecha_de_expedicion = (isset($_POST['fecha_de_expedicion'])) ? $_POST['fecha_de_expedicion'] : '';
$telefono_o_celular = (isset($_POST['telefono_o_celular'])) ? $_POST['telefono_o_celular'] : '';
$direccion = (isset($_POST['direccion'])) ? $_POST['direccion'] : '';
$correo = (isset($_POST['correo'])) ? $_POST['correo'] : '';
$eps = (isset($_POST['eps'])) ? $_POST['eps'] : '';
$arl = (isset($_POST['arl'])) ? $_POST['arl'] : '';
$afp = (isset($_POST['afp'])) ? $_POST['afp'] : '';
$departamento_name = (isset($_POST['departamento_name'])) ? $_POST['departamento_name'] : '';
$ciudad_name = (isset($_POST['ciudad_name'])) ? $_POST['ciudad_name'] : '';
$opcion = (isset($_POST['opcion'])) ? $_POST['opcion'] : '';
$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : '';



switch($opcion){
    case 1: //alta
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO `conductores` ( nombre_y_apellidos, tipo_de_documento, numero_de_documento, fecha_de_expedicion, telefono_o_celular, direccion, correo, eps, arp, afl, departamento_name, ciudad_name) VALUES( '$nombre_y_apellidos', '$tipo_de_documento', '$numero_de_documento', '$fecha_de_expedicion', '$telefono_o_celular', '$direccion', '$correo', '$eps', '$arl', '$afp', '$departamento_name', '$ciudad_name' ) ";          
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute(); 
        
        $consulta = "SELECT id, nombre_y_apellidos, tipo_de_documento, numero_de_documento, fecha_de_expedicion, telefono_o_celular, direccion, correo, eps, arl, afp, departamento_name, ciudad_name FROM conductores ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;
    case 2: //modificación
        $consulta = "UPDATE conductores SET nombre_y_apellidos='$nombre_y_apellidos', numero_de_documento='$numero_de_documento', direccion='$direccion' WHERE id='$id' ";      
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();        
        
        $consulta = "SELECT id, nombre_y_apellidos, tipo_de_documento, numero_de_documento, telefono_o_celular, direccion, correo, eps, afp, arl, departamento_name, ciudad_name FROM conductores WHERE id='$id' ";       
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;        
    case 3://baja
        $consulta = "DELETE FROM conductores WHERE id='$id'";       
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();    
        
        $consulta = "SELECT id, nombre_y_apellidos, tipo_de_documento, numero_de_documento, telefono_o_celular, direccion, correo, eps, afp, arl, departamento_name, ciudad_name FROM conductores WHERE id='$id' ";       
        $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado->execute();
        $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;        
}

print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //enviar el array final en formato json a JS
$conexion = NULL;
```

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="ModalConductores"tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title text-center" id="tituloCond"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
  <form  id="formConductores" name="formConductores" class="was-validated" enctype:"multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body m-4">
       <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
            Especiales Altagama Seccion Conductores
              </div>
             <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">! Vea Pongame Cuidado ! </h5>
                     <p class="card-text">Estamos a tan solo unos segundos de Registrar un nuevo conductor.</p>
                     <a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" id="charla" title="Requerimientos Previos" data-content="Antes de registrar un conductor este debe  haber cumplido los estandares de la empresa.">Información Importante</a>
                    </div>
                     <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                       Si ya leyo, Siga Pues...
                   </div>
                     </div>
          <br>
       <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="nombre_y_apellidos">Nombre y Apellidos:</label>
               <input class="form-control" maxlenght=80 type="text" name="nombre_y_apellidos" id="nombre_y_apellidos" placeholder="Nombre Completo" style="text-transform:uppercase;" value=""  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
           
           <div class="invalid-tooltip">
           Ve acordate que no puede tener mas de 80!
           </div>
           </div>

         <div class="col-md-4">
               <label for="tipo_de_documento">Tipo de Documento:</label>
               <select class="form-control"  name="tipo_de_documento" id="tipo_de_documento" required="required">
               <option value="">Seleciona un tipo de Documento</option>
               <option value="CC">CÉDULA DE ciudad_nameANÍA</option>
               <option value="CE">CÉDULA DE EXTRANJERÍA</option>
               <option value="CONTRASEÑA">CONTRASEÑA</option>
               <option value="NIT">NIT</option>
               <option value="PA">PASAPORTE</option>
               <option value="RC">REGISTRO CIVIL</option>
               <option value="AS">ADULTO SIN IDENTIDAD</option>
               </select>
               <div class="valid-tooltip">
                Pilas con ese nombre!
               </div>
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-4">
         <label for="numero_de_documento">Numero de Documento:</label>
               <input class="form-control" type="number" id="numero_de_documento" name="numero_de_documento" placeholder="Numero de Documento" required="required">
               <div class="valid-tooltip">
                Se ve Maravilloso!
               </div>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <label for="fecha_expedicion">Fecha de Expedicion del Documento:</label>
               <input class="form-control" type="date" id="fecha_de_expedicion" name="fecha_de_expedicion"  required="required">
               <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                Fresco solo Coloca una fecha!
               </div>
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-4">
           <label for="telefono_o_celular">Telefono de Celular:</label>
               <input class="form-control" type="number" id="telefono_o_celular" name="telefono_o_celular" placeholder="Telefono o Celular" required="required">
               <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                Fresco solo Coloca un Celular!
               </div>
         </div>
       
       
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <label for="correo">Correo Electronico:</label>
                  <input class="form-control"  required="required" type="email" id="correo" name="correo" placeholder="Correo Electronico" style="text-transform:uppercase;" value=""  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
                  <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                  Ve Acordate que el Modelo de Correo es Alejo@dominio.ext!
                 </div>

         </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <label for="eps">Eps:</label>
                  <select class="form-control"  name="eps" id="eps" required>
                  <option></option>
                  <option value="ASMET SALUD">ASMET SALUD</option>
                  <option value="ASOCIACION DE INDIGENAS DEL CAUCA- AIC- EPS INDIGENA">ASOCIACION DE INDIGENAS DEL CAUCA- AIC- EPS INDIGENA</option>
                  <option value="BARRANQUILLA SANA E.P.S">BARRANQUILLA SANA E.P.S</option>
                  <option value="BARRIOS UNIDOS DE QUIBDO  EPS AMBUQ -ESS">BARRIOS UNIDOS DE QUIBDO  EPS AMBUQ -ESS  </option>
                  <option value="CAFESALUD">CAFESALUD</option>
                  <option value="CAFESALUD E.P.S">CAFESALUD E.P.S</option>
                  <option value="CAJANAL E.P.S.">CAJANAL E.P.S. </option>
                  <option value="CALISALUD E.P.S">CALISALUD E.P.S</option>
                  <option value="CAPRECOM E.P.S.">CAPRECOM E.P.S.</option>
                  <option value="CAPRESOCA E.P.S">CAPRESOCA E.P.S</option>
                  <option value="CASA MADRE CANGURO">CASA MADRE CANGURO</option>
                  <option value="CENTRO MEDICO IMBANACO">CENTRO MEDICO IMBANACO</option>
                  <option value="CLÍNICA DE OCCIDENTE">CLÍNICA DE OCCIDENTE</option>
                  <option value="CLÍNICA NUESTRA">CLÍNICA NUESTRA</option>
                  <option value="CLÍNICA VERSALLES">CLÍNICA VERSALLES</option>
                  <option value="CLÍNICA SEBASTIÁN DE BELALCÁZAR">CLÍNICA SEBASTIÁN DE BELALCÁZAR</option>
                  <option value="COLMEDICA">COLMEDICA</option>
                  <option value="COLSEGUROS E.P.S">COLSEGUROS E.P.S</option>
                  <option value="COMFANDI">COMFANDI</option>
                  <option value="COMFENALCO">COMFENALCO</option>
                  <option value="COMFENALCO VALLE E.P.S">COMFENALCO VALLE E.P.S</option>
                  <option value="COMPENSAR E.P.S">COMPENSAR E.P.S</option>
                  <option value="COOMEVA">COOMEVA</option>
                  <option value="COOMEVA E.P.S.">COOMEVA E.P.S. </option>
                  <option value="COOSALUD">COOSALUD</option>
                  <option value="COSMITET">COSMITET</option>
                  <option value="CRUZ BLANCA">CRUZ BLANCA</option>
                  <option value="DIRECCIÓN DE SANIDAD POLICÍA NACIONAL">DIRECCIÓN DE SANIDAD POLICÍA NACIONAL</option>
                  <option value="E.P.S. CONDOR">E.P.S. CONDOR </option>
                  <option value="E.P.S. CONVIDA">E.P.S. CONVIDA </option>
                  <option value="E.P.S. DE CALDA">E.P.S. DE CALDA</option>
                  <option value="E.P.S. FAMISANA">E.P.S. FAMISANA</option>
                  <option value="E.P.S. PROGRAMA">E.P.S. PROGRAMA</option>
                  <option value="E.P.S. RISARALDA LTDA">E.P.S. RISARALDA LTDA</option>
                  <option value="E.P.S. SALUDCOOP">E.P.S. SALUDCOOP</option>
                  <option value="E.P.S. SÁNITAS">E.P.S. SÁNITAS </option>
                  <option value="E.P.S. SERVICIO OCCIDENTAL">E.P.S. SERVICIO OCCIDENTAL</option>
                  <option value="EMSSANAR">EMSSANAR</option>
                  <option value="EPS SANITAS">EPS SANITAS</option>
                  <option value="EPS SURA">EPS SURA</option>
                  <option value="FAMISANAR">FAMISANAR</option>
                  <option value="FONDO DE PASIVO SOCIAL DE FERROCARRILES NACIONALES DE COLOMBIA">FONDO DE PASIVO SOCIAL DE FERROCARRILES NACIONALES DE COLOMBIA</option>
                  <option value="FUNDACIÓN CLÍNICA VALLE DEL LILI">FUNDACIÓN CLÍNICA VALLE DEL LILI</option>
                  <option value="HOSPITAL MILITAR CENTRAL">HOSPITAL MILITAR CENTRAL</option>
                  <option value="HUMANA VIVIR S.A.">HUMANA VIVIR S.A.</option>
                  <option value="INSTITUTO DE SEGUROS">INSTITUTO DE SEGUROS</option>
                  <option value="MALLAMAS EPS">MALLAMAS EPS</option>
                  <option value="MEDIMAS EPS">MEDIMAS EPS</option>
                  <option value="METROPOLITANA DE SALUD">METROPOLITANA DE SALUD</option>
                  <option value="NUEVA EPS">NUEVA EPS</option>
                  <option value="PROFAMILIA">PROFAMILIA</option>
                  <option value="SALUD COLMENA E.P.S.">SALUD COLMENA E.P.S.</option>
                  <option value="SALUD TOTAL E.P.S">SALUD TOTAL E.P.S</option>
                  <option value="SALUDVIDA S.A. EPS">SALUDVIDA S.A. EPS</option>
                  <option value="SELVASALUD S.A. E.P.S">SELVASALUD S.A. E.P.S</option>
                  <option value="SERVICIO OCCIDENTAL DE SALUD">SERVICIO OCCIDENTAL DE SALUD</option>
                  <option value="SERVICIOS MÉDICOS">SERVICIOS MÉDICOS</option>
                  <option value="SOLSALUD E.P.S.">SOLSALUD E.P.S.</option>
                  <option value="SOS - SERVICIO OCCIDENTAL DE SALUD EPS">SOS - SERVICIO OCCIDENTAL DE SALUD EPS</option>
                  <option value="SURA">SURA</option>
                  <option value="SUSALUD E.P.S.">SUSALUD E.P.S.</option>
                  <option value="UNIMEC E.P.S. S.A.">UNIMEC E.P.S. S.A. </option>
                  <option value="UNISALUD PALMIRA">UNISALUD PALMIRA</option>
                  <option value="UNIVALLE">UNIVALLE</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Cuenta con EPS y de la buena!
               </div>
         </div>
        
       
         <div class="col-md-4">
           <label for="afp">Afp:</label>
               <select class="form-control"  name="afp" id="afp" required>
                 <option></option>
                 <option value="PROTECCIÓN S.A.">PROTECCIÓN S.A.</option>
                 <option value="SOCIEDAD ADMINISTRADORA DE FONDOS DE PENSIONES Y CESANTIAS PORVENIR S.A.">SOCIEDAD ADMINISTRADORA DE FONDOS DE PENSIONES Y CESANTIAS PORVENIR S.A.</option>
                 <option value="COLFONDOS PENSIONES Y CESANTÍAS">COLFONDOS PENSIONES Y CESANTÍAS</option>
                 <option value="OLD MUTUAL">OLD MUTUAL</option>
                 <option value="NO APLICA POR EDAD">NO APLICA POR EDAD</option>
                 <option value="FONDO NACIONAL DEL AHORRO">FONDO NACIONAL DEL AHORRO</option>
                 <option value="COLPENSIONES - ADMINISTRADORA COLOMBIANA DE PENSIONES">COLPENSIONES - ADMINISTRADORA COLOMBIANA DE PENSIONES</option>
               </select>                  
               <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Cuenta con AFP y de la buena!
               </div>
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="arl">Arl:</label>
                  <select class="form-control"  name="arl" id="arl" required>
                     <option></option>
                     <option value="ARL POSITIVA">ARL POSITIVA</option>
                     <option value="SEGUROS BOLÍVAR S.A">SEGUROS BOLÍVAR S.A</option>
                     <option value="SEGUROS DE VIDA AURORA S.A">SEGUROS DE VIDA AURORA S.A</option>
                     <option value="LIBERTY SEGUROS DE VIDA">LIBERTY SEGUROS DE VIDA</option>
                     <option value="MAPFRE COLOMBIA VIDA SEGUROS S.A.">MAPFRE COLOMBIA VIDA SEGUROS S.A.</option>
                     <option value="RIESGOS LABORALES COLMENA">RIESGOS LABORALES COLMENA</option>
                     <option value="SEGUROS DE VIDA ALFA S.A">SEGUROS DE VIDA ALFA S.A</option>
                     <option value="SEGUROS DE VIDA COLPATRIA S.A">SEGUROS DE VIDA COLPATRIA S.A</option>
                     <option value="SEGUROS DE VIDA LA EQUIDAD ORGANISMO C.">SEGUROS DE VIDA LA EQUIDAD ORGANISMO C.</option>
                     <option value="SURA - CIA. SURAMERICANA DE SEGUROS DE VIDA">SURA - CIA. SURAMERICANA DE SEGUROS DE VIDA</option>
               </select>
               <div class="valid-tooltip">
              Cuenta con ARL y de la buena!
               </div>
         </div>
       </div> 

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="lista_reproduccion">Departamento de Nacimiento:</label>
        <select id="lista_reproduccion" name="lista_reproduccion" class="form-control">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="videos">Ciudad de Nacimiento:</label>
      <select id="videos" name="videos" class="form-control">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <label for="direccion">Direccion:</label>
      <input class="form-control" required="required" type="text" id="direccion" name="direccion" placeholder="Direccion" style="text-transform:uppercase;" value=""  onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
      <div class="valid-tooltip">
              En que buen barrio vivis ve!
               </div>
               </div>
  </div>
       <br>
          <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center"> 
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                     <i class="far fa-window-close"></i> Cancelar
               </button> 
         
      
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="btnGuardar1" name="btnGuardar1" onclick="guardar()">
                      <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Registrar 
               </button>
          </div>


</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```

Comment: les dejp el crud.php

Comment: Arreglá por favor el código JS que pegaste, hay algo mal cerrado. Por otro lado, no encierres con las etiquetas de código el snippet, eso usalo solo para el código PHP.

Comment: Listo !!!! que pena habia copiado mal el codigo

Comment: Pero sigo con el problema

Comment: Debajo de `opcion = 1` tenés mal cerrada la función, escribiste `]);` y es `});`. Por otro lado, sumá el código HTML para ver de donde salen los inputs. Decís que no podes enviar datos y después decís que cuando guardas "se repite el último registro". Entonces, no se envían o se envían los datos incorrectos?

Comment: No se envian solo que como yo tengo en el success el console.log (data) pues esta data es el ultimo registro de mi bd por lo que en mi crudcond tengo que despues de insertar esos datos se me guarden en la variable data que despues sera mostrada en la consola

Comment: en resumidas cuentas no se estan enviado nada por el POST ya intente con la ayuda de Elmer pero nada....

Comment: Si hacés un `var_dump($_POST)` qué te devuelve? Probaste enviar con `FormData()` como dice Elmer? Cómo lo escribiste? Fijate en la solapa "network/red" te tu explorador que se está enviando cuando se ejecuta el envío por AJAX.

Comment: cuando hago el var_dump no me devuelve nada ya probe enviando mis datos con formdata y nada no se envian por ajax y no se porque y tengo otro crud y mi codigo corre hermos pero este no y hago el precedimiento igual pero no se envia nada por POST

Comment: que puedo hacer?

Comment: con el var dump me devuelve esto en la solapa [object Object] y arriba solicitr carga

Answer (score 0):

Esto podrías hacerlo escribiendo menos código.
prueba esto.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="un_nombre" id="un_nombre">

    <button type="button" name="Save" class="btn btn-primary" 
     onclick="guardar()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
     Guardar</button>
</form>


function guardar() {
   var formData;
   formData = new FormData($(".un_nombre")[0]);
   $.ajax({
       url:"bd/crudcond.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: formData,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (data) {
         //tu codigo aqui
      },
      error: function () {},
  });
}
```

formData = new FormData($(".hospital")[0]); con esto estas pasando todos los elementos de captura de datos como POST. los cuales estarán disponible en tu archivo crudcond.php, tal cual lo tienes:
$nombre_y_apellidos = (isset($_POST['nombre_y_apellidos']));

espero esto te ayude.

Comment: <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: data in C:\wamp64\www\App 5\dashboard\bd\crudcond.php on line <i>58</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th>
null

Comment: AHORA ME APARECE ESTO EN LA DATA DESPUÉS DEL SUCCES Y NO SE AGREGAN